# Find distinct Emails based on user column

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to figure out how to find first occurrence of distinct Emails based on user column ordered by time, so assume my table is like this

```
| User    | Email |  | Time|       |ID|
| David   | 1 |   | 2012/01/19 |   |1|
| David   | 2 |   | 2012/01/20 |   |2|
| David   | 2 |   | 2012/01/21 |   |1|
| David   | 2 |   | 2012/01/22 |   |2|
| David   | 2 |   | 2012/01/23 |   |1|
| David   | 3 |   | 2012/01/24 |   |2|
| David   | 3 |   | 2012/01/25 |   |1|
| John   | 1 |   | 2012/01/19 |   |1|
| John   | 1 |   | 2012/01/20 |   |2|
| John   | 1 |   | 2012/01/21 |   |1|
| John   | 2 |   | 2012/01/22 |   |2|
| John   | 2 |   | 2012/01/23 |   |1|
```

I want the result to look like this

```
| User     | Email |   | Time|       |ID|
| David   | 1 |     | 2012/01/19 |   |1|
| David   | 2 |     | 2012/01/20 |   |2|
| David   | 3 |     | 2012/01/24 |   |2|
| John   | 1 |      | 2012/01/19 |   |1|
| John   | 2 |      | 2012/01/22 |   |2|
```

What would be a good way to do this in MySQL? Distinct wouldn't work since it applies to all rows. I tried `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Email ORDER BY Time DESC) rnm` but this also doesn't work, as if you do `rnm = 1` it ignores all the following emails (and rnm between 1 and 10 would return duplicates). I'm not sure if there's a way to group this based on a different email from the same user

Comment: I think you want `PARTITION BY User, Email`

Answer (score 0):

You need to `PARTITION BY User, Email`. Also, to get the first occurrence, you need to order ascending, not descending.

```
WITH t AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY User, Email ORDER BY Time ASC) AS rn
    FROM yourTable
)
SELECT User, Email, Time, ID
FROM t
WHERE rn = 1
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5ybpM1pqJcoXobLcEXpP3d/1)

You would only need the window function if you want other columns from the same row as the minimum time.

Comment: Would this work if I have an additional row that can't be aggregated? Like if I have 2 records, they have the same user and email, but a different time and a different ID (1 and 2), if I use this group it should return both records because ID is different right? This way I get a duplicate user/email combination

Comment: There's no ID in the data you show. If you need the corresponding ID, you have to use the window function like I said in the answer.

Comment: Sorry about that. I've edited the question and added the ID column

Comment: Why do you have duplicate IDs in the table? Isn't it supposed to be a unique identifier for the row?

Comment: Those are not primary keys, they just act as placeholder for a variable

Comment: Anyway, that means you should go back to the window function, you just need to use the correct partitioning.